# Matlab: average each element in 2D array based on neighbors

Tags: arrays, matlab

I would like to average each element in array, `arr`, based on the elements immediately around it (including the current element) and store the new values in a different array.

For example, given the following array, `arr`, the first element in `newarr` would be the average of the values 92, 99, 98, and 80. The third element would be the average of 99, 1, 8, 80, 7,and 14.

Is there a faster way to do this than using several if statements in a for loop to check for corner and edge boundaries indicating the need to omit indices because they don't exist?

```
arr =

    92    99     1     8    15    67    74    51    58    40
    98    80     7    14    16    73    55    57    64    41
     4    81    88    20    22    54    56    63    70    47
    85    87    19    21     3    60    62    69    71    28
    86    93    25     2     9    61    68    75    52    34
    17    24    76    83    90    42    49    26    33    65
    23     5    82    89    91    48    30    32    39    66
    79     6    13    95    97    29    31    38    45    72
    10    12    94    96    78    35    37    44    46    53
    11    18   100    77    84    36    43    50    27    59
```

Comment: I'm assuming you'll want to do this based on first principles.  The duplicate post will give you that.  However, you can easily do this with 2D convolution:  `out = conv2(arr, (1/9)*ones(3,3), 'same');`

Comment: This divides the first element by 9 instead of 4, which is the number of elements I'm trying to average (when looking at the first element: 92, 99, 98, and 80). However, for an inner element, dividing by 9 is correct.

Comment: OK, I can reopen, but I have a couple of questions for you: (1) Do you have the image processing toolbox?  (2) What version of MATLAB do you have?

Comment: No need to reopen. I'm going to use your convolution solution in several steps: divide by 4when at the corners, divide by 6 when on the sides, and divide by 9 when in the middle.

Comment: Sounds good!  Yes, what you can do is along the corners, make sure you multiply by `9/4` to undo the division by 9, but then divide by 4.  Along the sides, multiply by `9/6`... so you can still use the convolution solution as I mentioned, but do this extra pre-processing to ensure things are correct.